# Assets Folder in flutter/ dart folder for client certificate authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, certificate, client

I am trying to do client certificate authenticiation in dart. But when I compile the app with flutter I keep getting cert.p12 not found. Here is my way of doing certificate authentication.

```
HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
final cert = "assets/cert.p12";
final password = "mittal";
final sc = SecurityContext.defaultContext
  ..useCertificateChain(cert, password: password)
  ..usePrivateKey(cert, password: password);
return super.createHttpClient(sc)
```

My assets folder is at the root of the project and cert.p12 is in it. Please help.

Here is a screenshot of android studio :

[The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxCEm.png)

I have read the https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images and and added, but still the same problem. Please Help

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/cert.p12
```

Comment: Please review [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) about how to declare and load and asset.

Comment: Hi, I revied that and have added this this to my pubspec.yaml. 
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/cert.p12.
But still that same problem

Comment: Please add `assets` part from you `pubspec.yaml` and your code where you try to get it. Also, be aware that adding an asset might not be reflected by hot restart / reload, to be sure restart your debugging session.

Comment: I don't really undertand what to do that, like  add assets part from pubspec.yaml

Comment: Ok, if you have `assets: - assets/cert.p12`, and you have this `cert.p12` file in your `assets` folder, how did you try to load it?

Comment: I tried to load it like this,  final sc = SecurityContext.defaultContext
      ..useCertificateChain(cert, password: password)
      ..usePrivateKey(cert, password: password);

Comment: and then  return super.createHttpClient(sc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually say this:

`String cert = "assets/cert.p12"` <-- you don't load the cert, you create a String.

This is an example how it works for me:

```
final clientCert = await rootBundle.load('assets/cert.p12');

context.useCertificateChainBytes(clientCert.buffer.asUint8List(), password: password);
```

This is a full example:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  ByteData clientCert;
  ByteData keystore;

  MyHttpOverrides({
    required this.clientCert,
    required this.keystore,
  });

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

    bool _certificateCheck(truststore, String host, int port) {
      return host == "test.backend.com";
    }

    String password = "password";

    context.useCertificateChainBytes(clientCert.buffer.asUint8List(), password: password);

    context.usePrivateKeyBytes(keystore.buffer.asUint8List(), password: password);

    HttpClient client = super.createHttpClient(context)..badCertificateCallback = (_certificateCheck);

    client..badCertificateCallback = (_certificateCheck);

    return client;
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  final clientCert = await rootBundle.load('assets/cert.pem');
  final keystore = await rootBundle.load('assets/key.pem');

  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides(
    clientCert: clientCert,
    keystore: keystore,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

These are the imports:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Comment: oh ok, so I changes useCertificateChain to useCertificateChainBytes and usePrivateKey to usePrivateKeyBytes. and load it like you wrote.

Comment: Now it makes createHttpClient into a future with async. and gives me an error.

Comment: it gives me this error  'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'HttpClient' is from 'dart:_http'.
Change to a subtype of 'HttpClient'.
  Future<HttpClient> createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) async {
                     ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/overrides.dart:72:14: Context: This is t
he overridden method ('createHttpClient').
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
             ^

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this without async ?

Comment: No. This is the way.

Comment: I used your solution to turn it for me. My solution was to create a contractor in my class. Then I used it in my method which calls this class.